# Spring Config Server secure prod, but not dev

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Is it possible to configure different security setup for different client profiles?

For example: allow fetching dev props, but for the prod require some authentication.

Problem is that client makes a request to

```
config/appName/profile,profile2[/label]
# application.properties
security.basic.path=/**/*profile1*/**,/**/*profile2*/**,/**/*etc*/**
```

Is this the only way?

Comment: Maybe a custom security filter would be a better choice

Comment: Java security config supports regexps, which looks slightly better:
.*prod.*